# Changed Django's primary key field, now items don't appear in the admin

Tags: django, django-models

I imported my (PHP) old site's database tables into Django. By default it created a bunch of primary key fields within the model (since most of them were called things like `news_id` instead of `id`).

I just renamed all the primary keys to `id` and removed the fields from the model. The problem then came specifically with my News model. New stuff that I add doesn't appear in the admin. When I remove the following line from my ModelAdmin, they show up:

```
list_display = ['headline_text', 'news_category', 'date_posted', 'is_sticky']
```

Specifically, it's the `news_category` field that causes problems. If I remove it from that list then I see my new objects. Now, when I edit those items directly (hacking the URL with the item ID) they have a valid category, likewise in the database. Here's the model definitions:

```
class NewsCategory(models.Model):

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.cat_name

    #news_category_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    cat_name = models.CharField('Category name', max_length=75)
    cat_link = models.SlugField('Category name URL slug', max_length=75, blank=True, help_text='Used in URLs, eg spb.com/news/this-is-the-url-slug/ - generated automatically by default')

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'news_categories'
        ordering = ["cat_name"]
        verbose_name_plural = "News categories"

class News(models.Model):

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.headline_text

    #news_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    news_category = models.ForeignKey('NewsCategory')
    writer = models.ForeignKey(Writer) # todo - automate
    headline_text = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    headline_link = models.SlugField('Headline URL slug', max_length=75, blank=True, help_text='Used in URLs, eg spb.com/news/this-is-the-url-slug/ - generated automatically by default')
    body = models.TextField()
    extra = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_sticky = models.BooleanField('Is this story featured on the homepage?', blank=True)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'news'
        verbose_name_plural = "News"
```

You can see where I've commented out the autogenerated primary key fields.

It seems like somehow Django thinks my new items don't have news_category_ids, but they definitely do. I tried editing an existing piece of news and changing the category and it worked as normal. If I run a search for one of the new items, it doesn't show up, but the bottom of the search says "1 News found", so something is going on.

Any tips gratefully received.

EDIT: here's my ModelAdmin too:

```
class NewsCategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"cat_link": ("cat_name",)}
    list_display = ['cat_name', '_cat_count']

    def _cat_count(self, obj):
        return obj.news_set.count()
    _cat_count.short_description = "Number of news stories"      

class NewsImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = NewsImage
    extra = 1    

class NewsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"headline_link": ("headline_text",)}
    list_display = ['headline_text', 'news_category', 'date_posted', 'is_sticky'] #breaking line
    list_filter = ['news_category', 'date_posted', 'is_sticky']
    search_fields = ['headline_text']
    inlines = [NewsImageInline]
```

Comment: did you migrate your database after you changed the models? try to remove the tables and run syncdb again

Comment: I ran a manual sql script to rename the columns, with the same effect. syncdb runs as normal.

Comment: are the primary keys in the database alright too? I mean you renamed the fields what happened to the primary keys?

Comment: Yeah, renaming the fields doesn't remove their key status, they're all still auto incrementing primary keys as normal.

Comment: one way to fix everything is to run syncdb to create another empty database alongside the one that you are trying to fix and compare the databases. then fix the original one, and return to using the original database in settings.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you are looking for I think would lie in the SQL schema that you altered and not in the django models.

It could probably have something to do with `null` or blank values in the `news_category_id`, or news that belongs to a category that doesn't exist in the news_category. Things I'd check:

- You have renamed the primary key on the News category from `news_category_id` to `id`. Does the foreign key on the News also map to `news_category_id` and not anything else?
- Are all the values captured in the `news.news_category` also present in `news_category.id`

Also, as an aside, I don't see any reason why you need to rename the primary keys to `id` from something that they already are. Just marking them `primary_key=True` works just fine. Django provides you a convenient alias `pk` to access a model's integer primary key, irrespective of what the name of the field actually is.

Comment: I thought that this could be it, but I know that the `news_category_id` values in the content I'm adding definitely exist in the `news_category` table.

The renamed primary keys match up (all the old records show the correct mapping).

I renamed it because of issues working with third party apps (django-taggit and Photologue). These apps wouldn't work when I tried to associate additional fields with the models - as soon as I used the default primary key, they worked.